# How do you build chroot jails with dnf?

Tags: fedora, dnf

Back in the day I used to build chroot jails using `yum`. It was simple, easy, and let me do things that weren't really available at the time (build packages for multiple distros on platforms like ia64 and ppc using the same infrastructure).

Fast forward 5 years, I'd like to build a simple chroot jail on Fedora 23. However, `dnf` doesn't make this easy. I used to be able to just create an `/etc/yum.repo.d/` file in the jail dir and call `yum --installroot`. Unfortunately `dnf` is still reading the local repo and not the one created in the chroot jail.

Is it possible to have `dnf` use conf files that aren't `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf` or in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`?

Comment: So it turns out that adding `--releasever=23` made the install work with my local repos, but it still doesn't let me reference a different repo that is not part of my install. This gets me what I want right now, but doesn't solve the root problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you found out, with dnf you need to specify the `--releaserver` argument.

In addition, if you want to use repositories specific to the chroot, then you'll need a bit more work.

I find the easiest solution is to create your own `dnf.conf` file inside the chroot, put the repository configurations inside, and then use it.

For example, let's say you want to create a Fedora 24 chroot in the `$(pwd)/mychroot` folder, using only packages from the fedora and rpmfusion-free repositories.

You would create the `mychroot/etc/dnf/dnf.conf` file, with the following content:

```
[main]
gpgcheck=1
installonly_limit=3
clean_requirements_on_remove=True
reposdir=

[fedora]
name=Fedora $releasever - $basearch
failovermethod=priority
metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-$releasever-$basearch
skip_if_unavailable=False

[updates]
name=Fedora $releasever - $basearch - Updates
failovermethod=priority
metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-f$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
metadata_expire=6h
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-$releasever-$basearch
skip_if_unavailable=False

[rpmfusion-free]
name=RPM Fusion for Fedora $releasever - Free
metalink=https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/metalink?repo=free-fedora-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
metadata_expire=14d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-$releasever
```

(look at the `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo` files on your system and just copy-paste)

The important part is this line in the `main` section, which tells dnf not to search for repositories in any directory, but only in the main configuration file, which will make it ignore your system repositories:

```
reposdir=
```

Finally, you can run dnf:

```
# dnf -c $(pwd)/mychroot/etc/dnf/dnf.conf install --installroot=$(pwd)/mychroot --releasever=24 gstreamer1-libav
```

Comment: You can show it now!

Comment: And I finally did. Sorry it took me so long. :-/

Comment: I tried that, but all I get is `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lstrip'`

Answer (score 4):

Since 2016-10 or so Dnf has [changed its defaults](http://dnf.baseurl.org/2016/10/21/installroot-in-dnf-2-0/). That means when executing a command like

```
# dnf --installroot=/mnt/new-root --releasever=26 \
    group install custom-environment
```

Dnf [now looks first for](http://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#installroot-label) `etc/dnf/dnf.conf` and `etc/yum.repo.d` under `/mnt/new-root`, by default.

This default can be changed via specifying:

```
 --setopt=reposdir=/other/path --config /other/location/dnf.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

dnf allows setting any config option on the command line, and this includes `reposdir`.  It should be possible to use a command like this:

```
ROOT=/path/to/my/chroot
dnf --installroot="$ROOT" \
    -c "$ROOT"/etc/dnf/dnf.conf \
    --setopt=reposdir="$ROOT"/etc/yum.repos.d \
    install ...
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/197518)

Comment: @Thomas do you prefer this phrasing?